# "Design" library in Eclipse doesn't compile even with API 21

Tags: android, eclipse, android-design-library

So, after the `Design` [library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design) was released I rushed into getting it set up so I could start adding material design to my existing apps.

However, after following the usual instructions for setting up library projects in Eclipse (as per http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) I'm finding that the design library doesn't build out of the box.

The set of errors revolve around missing attribute tags in the xml. First and last being:

```
design\res\values\styles.xml:21: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
...
design\res\values\styles.xml:111: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'.
```

Now, I understand that many of you will dive on this saying "You need to compile with API 21 not with API 7 (which is it's out of the box value)". That was my first thought too - but even when compiling with API 21 (yes, after cleaning) it still *hates* these tags.

(As an aside, I also noticed that these tags are in the `/res/values/styles.xml` which would surely mean that these styles would be being used on API-7 devices - I'm assuming that at runtime these aren't a problem and are either ignored or compiled out).

Anyone encountered the same problem - and have an idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple answer:

The `design` library *requires* the v7/appcompat library as a parent library.

(You also need to update the project.properties of that library to API-21 to get it to compile)

See [this related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28981228/726954)